# How merge sub branch to main branch using clearcase command line under linux?

Tags: linux, merge, clearcase

I want to merge all the files labelled with `XXX` in sub branch `AAA` to main branch.

The main branch do not update since `AAA` branched out, so the merge task is just replace all changed files with sub branch files.

How can I do this using ClearCase command line (`cleartool`) under Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command `cleartool findmerge` for that.

The key is to use a view which select those files:

```
element * MYLABEL
element * /main/LATEST
```

And use `-ftag yourLabelView`

You can also directly use `-fver YourLabel` (meaning, no need to have a special dedicated view)

Go to a dynamic view set on `/main`, and do a:

```
cd /view/MyView/vobs/MyVob
cleartool findmerge . -fver MyLabel -whynot -print
```

The `-whynot` and `-print` allow you to **preview** what would be merge and see if that fits what you expect.

Once the preview seems good:

```
cleartool findmerge . -c "Merge MyLabel on main" –fver MyLabel –merge
```

Comment: And what if I need to check if merge is needed to tens of thousands of files,
Is there an easy way that when using –print it will show only items that Needs Merge ?
Also it there a way that the actual merge will be done only in case merge is automatic ?

Comment: @Elad `-print` won't do any merge, only preview. `-gmerge` will perform the merges, automatically if there are no conflict.