# Merge all files from a branch into main(using a command/script) cleartool

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I want to merge all files from a particular branch to main using a script or a command. Is there a way to do it  without checking out each file in target or should i do each file manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClearCase is file-based, not repository-based: any merge will be done file by file, and actually first folder by folder (you merge the folders first, then the files).

The easiest way to initiate a merge based on a branch is to use the [`cleartool findmerge`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_findmerge.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.0%2F9-1-0-1-15&lang=en), which can use a version selector, like `-fve/rsion .../branch1/LATEST`.
See also "[To prepare to merge](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/t_borg_prepngmrg.htm?lang=en)"

The usual approach though is to use a view or a tag to select the elements you want to merge, as I described in "[How merge sub branch to main branch using clearcase command line under linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17853955/6309)" (using `-ftag`).

Note that this works also in an [UCM environment, based on activities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17697198/6309) (even though the deliver and rebase commands remain the recommended merge methods).

Comment: I actually wanted a command to list all the files checked in to a particular branch, so i can iterate it checkout the file in main  and merge each file individually .

Comment: @Learner findmerge is much more convenient than trying to implement it manually. But to list files in a given branch: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2786120/6309